# What is the better way to retrieve URL of the template directory: bloginfo('template_url') or echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() )?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using the [Theme Check](http://themecheck.org/) for test the quality of my theme, it return my theme is using the `bloginfo();` 
 Ex: `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/static/img/logo.svg"`

The Theme Check recommended that I replace the `bloginfo()` for `echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );`

I searched about it, but I'm not sure if using this function is a good practice.

So, it's correct use `echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );` for call any files in my theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bloginfo('template_url')` calls `get_bloginfo('template_url', 'display')` and that function retrieves the output of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

So using `get_template_directory_uri()` directly will **reduce 2 function calls**.

I don't know if to use `esc_url()` make sense here. The function `get_template_directory_uri()` has is own little part to clean URL's:

```
$template = str_replace( '%2F', '/', rawurlencode( get_template() ) );
```

Source: [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

---

In the startertheme [_s](https://github.com/Automattic/_s) from [Automatic](https://www.automatic.com/) (the company behind wordpress), they use `get_template_directory_uri()` directly without `esc_url()`.

Look here: [functions.php](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/functions.php)

---

My recommendation:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/static/img/logo.svg"`

Answer (score 1):

`bloginfo('template_url')` internally uses `get_template_directory_uri()`.

So, It's better to use `get_template_directory_uri()` to access files in your themes folder.

And it's a good practise to use esc_rul which sanitizes the the URLs.

> Always use esc_url when sanitizing URLs (in text nodes, attribute
>   nodes or anywhere else). Rejects URLs that do not have one of the
>   provided whitelisted protocols (defaulting to http, https, ftp, ftps,
>   mailto, news, irc, gopher, nntp, feed, and telnet), eliminates invalid
>   characters, and removes dangerous characters.

Refer below links for more details:

- [esc_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url)
- [get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)